# Find All Tests Not in a List

Tags: mstest

I have all the tests for my web application (written with the Visual Studio test framework -- Microsoft.Quality DLLs) divided into several (currently two) ordered tests. **Is there an easy way to find all the tests that are not in any list?**

(The reason I need to use ordered tests is because the initial tests test that installation/setup/configuration of my application worked, and subsequent tests would fail without that.)

Comment: I would strongly suggest to refactor your test to they don't depend on each other. What if you would move your initialization code to a TestInitialize method (also not the best solution but better then ordered tests!)

Comment: @WouterdeKort agreed, although my hands are tied. My application installs itself, and then runs normally. Therefore, I have to test that it can install itself, and then test that it runs properly after installing; so I must (sadly) therefore force the installation tests to run first (after they wipe out the DB), and then I'm good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's on easy way to do this. The best thing to do is switch to a framework that doesn't require every test to be on a list -- I recommend MbUnit. It has a great `DependsOn` attribute to easily configure dependencies between tests.